# Displaying List Of JavaScript Objects As HTML List Items

Tags: javascript, html, object, for-loop, html-lists

When I attempt this, the HMTL page only displays the last object, instead of all the objects.

Here is my JavaScript file

```
var family = {
  aaron: {
    name: 'Aaron',
    age: 30
  },
  megan: {
    name: 'Megan',
    age: 40
  },
  aaliyah: {
    name: 'Aaliyah',
    age: 2
  }
}

var list = function(family) {
  for (var prop in family) {
    var elList = document.getElementById('aaron-family').innerHTML = prop;
  }
}

list(family);
```

And here's my HTML file

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Aaron's Test With Objects</title>
</head>
  <li id="aaron-family">Hey, this is where it goes</li>
<footer>
  <script src="objects.js"></script>
</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to append new items to the list.

Answer (score 7):

Thank you guys! Here's the final solution I came up with:

JS

```
var family = {
  aaron: {
    name: 'Aaron',
    age: 30
  },
  megan: {
    name: 'Megan',
    age: 40
  },
  aaliyah: {
    name: 'Aaliyah',
    age: 2
  }
}

var list = function(family) {
  for (var prop in family) {
    document.getElementById('aaron-family').innerHTML += '<li>' + prop + '</li>';
    console.log(prop);
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Aaron's Test With Objects</title>
</head>
<ul id="aaron-family">
</ul>
<footer>
  <script src="objects.js"></script>
</footer>
</html>
```

I'm sure it can be refactored but it works, visually.

Comment: You might want to move the `document.getElementById` outside of the for loop because each loop you are doing a query for that id:)

Answer (score 3):

Well, you've got a couple problems there (`<li>` tag without a parent `<ol>` or `<ul>` tag, among others)...but I'd say the primary error is that you are replacing each subsequent output with each assignment to `innerHTML`.

Solution: assign a compiled array to `innerHTML` (using `join` to include spaces between the values)

```
var list = function(family) {
  var names = [];
  for (var prop in family) {
    names.push(prop.name);
  }
  document.getElementById('aaron-family').innerHTML = names.join(' ');
}
list(family);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `elList` because there is no point in having it...

Then change

```
document.getElementById('aaron-family').innerHTML = prop;
```

To

```
document.getElementById('aaron-family').innerHTML += prop;
```

That way you are not constantly setting the `innherHTML` to `prop`. Also, you might find it better to change the function to the following in order to prevent from constantly getting the element.

```
function list(family) {
  var elList = document.getElementById('aaron-family');
  for (var prop in family) {
    elList.innerHTML += prop;
  }
}
```

---

Hope this helps:)

Answer (score 1):

This dynamic way to render like this data format into HTML

```
const elList = document.getElementById('aaron-family')

function convertObjectsToArrayOfObjects(family) {
    const filteredData = []
    for(person in family){
          filteredData.push(family[person])
     }
    return filteredData;
 }

function elList(family) {
   const familyData = convertObjectsToArrayOfObjects(family)
   elList.innerHTML = `
      ${
        familyData.map(person => {
          return `
            <h1>name: ${person.name}</h1>
            <h2>age: ${person.age}</h2>
          `   
       })
     }
  `
}

list(family);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just you don't need to define function

html file:

```js
var family = {
    aaron: {
        name: 'Aaron',
        age: 30
    },
    megan: {
        name: 'Megan',
        age: 40
    },
    aaliyah: {
        name: 'Aaliyah',
        age: 2
    }
}

for (var prop in family) {

    document.getElementById('aaron-family').innerHTML += '<li>' + prop + '</li>';

}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Aaron's Test With Objects</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <ul id="aaron-family">
        </ul>
        <script src="objects.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```